# Divide a Line with Canvas - Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have drawn a line, using `canvas.drawline` method:

```
canvas.drawLine(anterior.mRelativeX, anterior.mRelativeY, atual.mRelativeX, atual.mRelativeY, mPaint);
```

Now I want to **divide** this line, for example, divide it by 5 equal parts, and retrieve the `X, Y` for these 5 points so I can draw a little dot using `canvas.drawCircle`:

```
canvas.drawCircle(mRelativeX, mRelativeY, mRadius, mPaint);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of line is not needed.

If you want to divide the line into `k` equal parts, you will need `k-1` points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the equation of your line, then you can easily get an Y for any X value. After that, just divide the X in 5 parts and find the corresponding Y.

Take a look at http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html